# iOS The viewcontrollers in the storyboard are grouped into another storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

#### The answer I found after a week

I am trying to copy a storyboard's cell to another cell and it succeeds. Then I thought if it would work if I copied the viewcontroller directly to another storyboard, the answer is yes. I am very sorry that I can't upload the image details.

This is the step:

- 1、Select `View Controller Scene` in the `storyboard` and copy it.
- 2、To another `storyboard` you need to move to, paste
- 3、Delete the `View Controller Scene` in the `storyboard` in the first step.

If you have other answers, please give me the answer, thank you very much.

---

**The following is my original question**

Before the storyboard didn't divide the business, many different business pages were in a storyboard, and now I want to group them out. Grouped into multiple storyboards by business, just like folder grouping.

#### Example:

`A.storyboard` contains `a.viewcontroller`, `b.viewcontroller`, `c.viewcontroller`, `d.viewcontroller`

Because of business needs, you need to group `a.viewcontroller`, `b.viewcontroller` to `B.storyboard`.

#### Some methods

I noticed a feature of `Xcode`, `Editor -> Refactor to Storyboard`, which narrows the selected `viewcontroller` to a reference tag and points to another `Storyboard`. But this can only be done by grouping a `viewcontroller` into a `Storyboard`. It is not possible to group multiple `viewcontroller`s into a `Storyboard`.

So can I group multiple `viewcontroller`s in the current `Storyboard` to another `Storyboard`? Do you need to start with `Source Code`? If you know the method, please let me know, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

This is a good way to write codes.

[group multiple viewcontrollers in the Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/braM5.png)

Comment: You may understand wrong, I need to refactor the viewcontroller in the storyboard, what I need is to move the existing viewcontroller to other storyboards.

Comment: I found a solution, directly select "View Controller Scene" to copy, and then paste it in other storyboard, and finally delete the original. Finally, I have to close this question.